# traefik custom rule PathStrip does not match

Tags: traefik

TRying out custome rule in traefik ..

it should

- Remove /code from the url and send remaining to backend based on the other matcher

Example url : /code/rr ; 
   only /rr should be sent to backend .. Looks like only /code is sent to backend.

Below is my rule , but not working ..

```
      [frontends.f_rr]
       entrypoints = ["http","https"]
       priority = 10
         passHostHeader = true
       backend = "b_co"
        [frontends.f_co.routes.test_1]
        rule = "PathStrip: /code/; Path:/rr"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `PathPrefixStrip: /code` rule (and only this rule). It catches all requests for the `/code` path prefix but strips it prior to forwarding to the backend.

See also the documentation at https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#frontends, in particular the subsection titled *Path Matcher Usage Guidelines*.

Comment: actually there are multiple backends, expecting urls without /code .. example : /code/rr to backend_rr only sending /rr ; /code/kk to backend_kk only sending /kk ;

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but you could try to add the `ReplacePath` modifier to the mix. That is, try something like `PathPrefixStrip: /code; ReplacePath: /rr`.

Comment: Possibly also `AddPrefix`? On the phone right now, so I can't test / check.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue with `stripprefix` middleware. The way to go about it, is after you define the router and the middleware, you actually need to assign the middleware to the router for it to be usable. Otherwise it will be defined and created but not used (You can use traefik dashboard to see if the middleware is being used by any router)

Using docker provider:

```
  traefik.enable: true
  traefik.port: 9101
  # define router
  traefik.http.routers.my-router.rule: PathPrefix(`/my-router`)
  # only if accepts htpps
  traefik.http.routers.my-router.tls: true
  # strippath middleware
  traefik.http.middlewares.my-router-strip.stripprefix.prefixes: '/my-router'
  # assign to router, do n ot forget this bit
  traefik.http.routers.my-router.middlewares: my-router-strip@docker
  traefik.http.middlewares.my-router.stripprefix.forceslash: false
  traefik.http.routers.my-router.entrypoints: https, http
```